# Replace gradient with solid colour on PNG/JPEG with Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, gradient, cs5

First  of all thanks for taking the time to read my question and my apologies if this has already been addressed (I did research on the website but couldn't find anything).

I am currently teaching myself the basics of Photoshop and am trying to replace the gradient part of a picture with a solid colour but did not managed to do it yet. (See the image I'm working on [here](https://www.hacpac.org/event/roald-dahls-matilda-the-musical-jr/))

I tried the replace colour technique, and also tried to play with the hue/saturation of a layer but nothing works.

Basically, I'd like to have the blue-3D part to be yellow (255-224-63), but when using the layer technique it ends up being green and not yellow. As for the replace colour technique, it gets very much pixellated which is more than annoying.

Does anyone have a better technique to achieve the result I'ma aiming at?

Thanks very much in advance for your time.

Ed

Answer (score 5):

- Make a Polygonal Lasso around the 3D text, it doesn't have to be perfect, just avoiding the rest of the elements
- From the **Layers Panel**, click the Adjustment Layer icon at the bottom to create a Hue/Saturation Layer

  - At the Hue/Saturation Panel, click **Colorize**, increase the saturation and move the HUE slider to the yellow part

[image]

Comment: Hi Danielillo, 

I struggled a bit with the polygonal lasso tool (I guess I wasn't precise enough) but managed in the end. 

Thanks very much for your swift answer.

Ed,

Answer (score 3):

**Another Solution which i mostly use when i have white&coloured combo**

In that case i avoid using hue saturation and rather i uses color overlay in color mode.

=> Create selection via Lasso tool (L) and <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd> to create layer by selection.

=> Double click layer and go to `Color Overlay` and then choose yellow color and change it's mode to `Color` and voila you're done

=> Below is animated GIF to understand more :) Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: Hi Design Phoenix, 

Thanks for your quick answer. It really helped. 

Plus, the GIF was really useful as I could replicate the process step by step.

I now know how to quickly replace a colour. 

Ed,

Comment: It's okay :) Danielilo's answer is also good since in his answer you can increase and decrease shine level but if you want to keep same depth as original use my method else follow him and if any of our answer solved your problem don't forget to mark it as accepted :) Regards